# Magento 2: Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

Tags: magento2, htaccess, permissions, apache

My Magento 2 development system started, at (seemingly) random, to display the following error for all my frontend JS files

> Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

This error persists even after I (temporarily) `chmod 777` all my `.htaccess` files

```
$ find pub -name .htaccess -exec ls -ld '{}' \;
-rwxrwxrwx  1 alanstorm  staff  5544 Nov 20 10:44 pub/.htaccess
-rwxrwxrwx  1 alanstorm  staff  72 Nov 20 10:44 pub/errors/.htaccess
-rwxrwxrwx  1 alanstorm  staff  3389 Nov 20 10:44 pub/media/.htaccess
-rwxrwxrwx  1 alanstorm  staff  31 Nov 20 10:44 pub/media/customer/.htaccess
-rwxrwxrwx  1 alanstorm  staff  31 Nov 20 10:44 pub/media/downloadable/.htaccess
-rwxrwxrwx  1 alanstorm  staff  31 Nov 20 10:44 pub/media/import/.htaccess
-rwxrwxrwx  1 alanstorm  staff  88 Nov 20 10:44 pub/media/theme_customization/.htaccess
-rwxrwxrwx  1 alanstorm  staff  3300 Nov 20 10:44 pub/static/.htaccess
```

What's the deal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to check the permissions on the **parent** directory.  For example, if you're seeing this error when you request

> http://magento-2-with-keys.dev/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Magento_Customer/js/customer-data.js

Make sure your permissions are right on

```
ls -ld pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Magento_Customer

$ ls -ld pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Magento_Customer
drwxrwx---  8 alanstorm  staff  272 Dec 14 16:25 pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Magento_Customer
```

Magento 2's core seems a little inconsistent about `umasks` and permissions, and created folders will often be missing the execute permission for the global permission set.  I'm guessing the core team doesn't use MOD_PHP much, and opts instead for one of PHP's FastCGI implementations.

Comment: what if *pub/static/frontend* is empty?